# After setting Change Notification(subscring) a service using Ms graph how to get the notification in visual studio from Azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I could subscribe Online meeting/calls by using this graph api request in C# and set the notification url to azure function app. It works perfectly and I could see the notification in Azure function app. Is there any way to get the notification from azure function app to visual studio using C# program or graph api request.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
```

Content-Type: application/json

```
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://notificationes.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=h61e/.............",
  "resource": "/communication/callrecords",
  "includeResourceData": true,
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-05-9T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "{secretClientState}"
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the notification sent to your local machine?

Comment: Hi, if the solution provided below helps your problem, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can see the notifications in your function logs, so you can also get the notifications according to get logs of your function.

You can use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/execute) for application insight to get the logs of your function. Do a post request of this api in your c# code in visual studio and then parse the response data, you can get the notifications in the logs.

If you do not know how to request the api, you can go to your function on azure portal and click "Monitor" tab.

[image]

Then press "F12" to open the browser developer tools and click one of the logs in "Monitors". You can see the request in backend of browser.

[image]

Click the query request, you can find the details of the query request like below screenshot. Then you can imitate it to write your query request in your code.

[image]